# How do I get a particular labeled version of a folder in Borland StarTeam?

Tags: version-control, starteam

I'm about to perform a bunch of [folder moving operations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28578/how-can-i-merge-my-files-when-the-folder-structure-has-changed-using-borland-st) in StarTeam (including some new nesting levels) and I would like to set a label so that I can roll back in case of issues.  I figured out how to set a label on a folder and all its children, but I couldn't figure out how to get the version of that folder corresponding to that particular label.  It seems like labels are tied to the files themselves and not the folders/folder structure.

Comment: Your link points to the beta Stackoverflow, so it's broken, now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've switched to Subversion and FogBugz so I am rusty on StarTeam. I think you need a  View Label.

1. From `View` menu, select `Labels...` to open the Labels dialog.
2. On the `View` tab, click `New...` button to open View Label dialog.
3. Type in label name as "Release 1.2.3.4", check `Frozen`, and hit `OK`.

To get back to the state,

1. From `View` menu, select `Select Configuration...` to open the Select a View Configuration dialog.
2. Select `Labeled configuration`, and pick "Release 1.2.3.4"

You can then create a new view from the view label to branch off you want to. See the Help file > `Working with StarTeam` > `Managing Views`. Here's a quote from `Configuring a View`:

> By default, a view has a current
>   configuration – that is, it displays
>   the latest revisions of the items in
>   the project. However, you can roll
>   back a view to a past state based on a
>   label, promotion state, or a point in
>   time.